# alignment get corrupted in IE10

Tags: html, css

I have css code , with header and footer. And signout in left side bar when I open IE10 alignment is good for signout, but when I open it in IE9,8,7,6 alignment for signout coming in the center of the page when I fix the  alignment for signout in IE9,8,7,6 it get corrupted in IE10.
How to fix the issue so signout stay in its place left side bar in both IE10 and IE9,8,7,6

you can see my web at http://jsfiddle.net/hadinetcat/E8jd3/5/

**css**

```
.container3 {
float:left;
width:100%;
/*background:green;*/
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
}

.container2 {
float:left;
width:100%;
background:FFA500;
position:relative;
right:45%;
}

.container1 {
float:left;
width:100%;
/*background:red;*/
position:relative;
right:40%;
}

.col1 {
float:left;
width:26%;
position:relative;
left:87%;
overflow:hidden;
height:570px;
}

.col2 {
float:left;
width:50%;
position:relative;
left:90%;
overflow:hidden;
}

.col3 {
float:left;
width:26%;
position:relative;
left:80%;
overflow:hidden;
}


.footer {
        border:1px solid orange;
        position: relative;
        padding:0px;
        margin-top:-5px;
    font-size:15px;
    bottom:36px;

    }


.signout {
 position:       relative;
 width:          200;
 bottom:         150px;
 left:           20px;
 }
```

**html**

```
<div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;">

<h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Wellcome To Balhalfe Services Customer Reports</h1>

<div class="container3 ">
<div class="container1 ">
<div class="container2 ">


<div class="col1">

lalalallalalalallala <br />
lllllllllllllllllllll <br />

</div>


<div class="col2">

<div align="center">
        <H2 align="center"> Report Table</H></div> 

<table border="1" align="center"> 
        <tr>
                <td><b>Name</b></td>
                <td><b>Mime</b></td>
                <td><b>Size (bytes)</b></td>
                <td><b>Created</b></td>
                <td><b>Download</b></td>
            </tr>




            <tr>
                <td>1594(HA 10 AL HAALY).pdf</td>
                <td>application/pdf</td>
                <td>60964</td>
                <td>2013-08-29 23:40:07</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=6&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr>

<tr>
                <td>eu contres.txt</td>
                <td>text/plain</td>
                <td>546</td>
                <td>2013-08-22 00:06:55</td>
                <td><a style='text-decoration:none;'href=' get_file_work.php?id=4&company=companya'>Download</a></td>
            </tr></table>

</div>


<div class="col3">

</div>

</div>

</div>


<div class="signout">

<a  style='text-decoration:none;' href= "index.html">Sign Out </br></a>

</div>


<div class="footer" style="background-color:#FFA500;clear:both;text-align:center;">
Copyright © balhalfe services 20103-2014</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.signout` should be `position:absolute; clear:left;` not `position:relative;`. `position:absolute;` is `relative` to the last parent `position:relative;`.

The below information will still help in the future:

Since IE 10 does not accept the IE specific HTML to control CSS. I use the following code:

```
var doc = document, bod = doc.body, IE = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split('MSIE')[1]);
function gteIE(version, className){
  if(IE >= version){
    bod.className = className;
  }
}
gteIE(10, 'ie10');
```

Now, just make sure you specify the `.ie10` in your CSS.

Comment: can you please explain for me step by step where shell i add this ??

Comment: do i have to use jquery for this ??

Comment: You add this to an external JavaScript page. Call it `common.js` then use a `script` tag like `<script type='text/javascript' src='common.js'></script>`. Then on your CSS stylesheet you just do something like `.ie10 .otherclass{/*CSS here*/}`. So the CSS formula is simply `.ie10` with a space after it then any other selector/s after that. That JavaScript is just changing the className of your `body` Element, so all of the `body` descendants can be accessed with the space then more CSS.

Comment: no i tried your way but not helping, still when i access it from IE10 its in left side bar, when i access it from IE9,8,7,6 it gos to center of the page. the signout any other solution??

Comment: one more thing after doing you code signout became behind the color how to bring her back..

Comment: it work with only changing to position:absolute; with out the code thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add `clear: both;` to your `.signout` to clear all the floated columns.